# What is the difference between "using T::member" and "using namespace"?

Tags: c++, namespaces, keyword, using, using-declaration

What is the difference between these two usage of `using` keyword:

```
using boost::shared_ptr;
```

and

```
using namespace boost;
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
using boost::shared_ptr;
```

Includes only the `shared_ptr` from the `boost` namespace in your current namespace.
This means you can use the `shared_ptr` without qualifying it with namespace `boost`.

It is called a **using declaration**.

---

```
using namespace boost;
```

Includes all the symbols in the `boost` namespace in your current scope.
This means you can use all the symbols in the `boost`namespace without qualifying them with namespace `boost`.

It is called as **using directive**.

---

***Why should you always prefer `using declaration` over `using directive`?***

It is always better to use the first(`using declaration`) and avoid the second(`using directive`) because the second causes **namespace pollution** by bringing in potentially huge numbers of names in to the current namespace, many of which are unnecessary. The presence of the unnecessary names greatly increases the possibility of unintended name conflicts.

To quote `Herb Sutter` on the usage of `using directive`:

***I find it helpful to think of a `using directive` as a marauding army of crazed barbarians that sows indiscriminate destruction wherever it passes--something that by its mere presence can cause `unintended conflicts,` even when you think you're allied with it.***

Comment: "It is better to use the first." Not necessarily.

Comment: Yes, necessarily, as it significantly reduces the namespace pollution.

Comment: @David Heffernan: "Not necessarily" unless you want to cause namespace pollution.

Comment: @DeadMG `using namespace` is widely used in standard library header files  for example. In that situation the pollution is intentional.

Comment: @David: a quick search of the stantard headers in gcc 4.2 found that only `debug/debug.h` (which is an implementation detail) employs the `using namespace`  directive, on the other hand, the `using` declaration is used over 1000 times.

Comment: Actually, have I remembered it the wrong way round? Perhaps what I'm thinking of is how newer C++ headers do things like `namespace xxx { #include <xxx.h> }`. Sorry.

Comment: @Als: the answer is missing some details, I am feeling too lazy to go and find all of them and check in the standard, but you can consider the case of implementing `swap` as a member function in a class: `struct X { int d; void swap( X& other ) { using std::swap; swap( d, other.d ); }` is correct, while replacing the *using declaration* with a *using directive* will fail to compile.

Comment: @David Heffernan: If by "not necessarily" you meant sometimes it is best to avoid using `using` altogether, I agree. On the other hand, if you meant that sometimes `using namespace` is preferred, I agree with Als.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: I just had a glance at the relevant parts in the standard and I will be frank that I don't feel inclined to delve too much deep in to those long paras and get more detail. This is partly because I am lazy right now(being a sunday) & atleast for me it is hard to understand the real meaning of quotes in standard unless I give it sufficiently long time to sink in, which I don't feel inclined to do in this case.

Answer (score 4):

- `using namespace boost` makes all names in the `boost` namespace visible without qualification
- `using boost::shared_ptr` just makes `shared_ptr` visible without qualification.

Answer (score 3):

The first is called [`using declaration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/was37tzw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx);

The second is called [`using directive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewtdfs3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Quoting MSDN:

> Note the difference between the using directive and the using
> declaration:
>
> the using declaration allows an individual name to be
> used without qualification,
>
> the using directive allows all the names
> in a namespace to be used without qualification.

Answer (score 1):

The first only allows you to use the name shared_ptr without the boost:: prefix. The second allows you to use any and all names in the boost namespace withoout the boost:: prefix. Some people frown on the latter but it's never given me any problems.