# alias using vs typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, alias, typedef, using

I'm working on a school lab and in the instruction it says:

> Change the typedef that defines Word_List to a alias declaration (using)

From what I've googled, the way to do this is to change from:

```
typedef vector<Word_Entry> Word_List;
```

to:

```
using Word_List = std::vector<Word_Entry>;
```

but when I compile, I get the following error:

```
error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'Word_List'
```

**Most of the code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Word_Entry
{
  string ord;
  unsigned cnt;
};

//typedef vector<Word_Entry> Word_List; <-This is what it used to look like
using Word_List = vector<Word_Entry>;


int main()
{
 ...
}
```

aditional info:

```
Yes, I am compiling with c++11 
Word_Entry is a struct that stores 2 variables
I have the line "using namespace std;" in the begining of my code
I'm using mingw compiler
```

Comment: Did you enable c++11 specification on your project or makefile?

Comment: I've added aditional info answering your questions

Comment: Could you post the whole file (or a simplified version of it that has the same error)? Theres not quite enough information to tell whats wrong.

Comment: Doesn't the `using` keyword operate on namespaces exclusively? I don't think you can use it for complete typedefs.

Comment: And inside the main? How are you trying to use it? Also, open up a cmd and do a `g++ --version` and add the output (the relevant line with version not the copyright bit).

Comment: As @H2CO3 said, I don't think it's supposed to work like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973161/c-using-keyword

Comment: @MihaiTodor It actually is supposed to work like that, its called [type-alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

Comment: What version is your MinGW? (first line in g++ --version)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the solution here:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Word_Entry
{
  string ord;
  unsigned cnt;
};

//typedef vector<Word_Entry> Word_List; <-This is what it used to look like
using Word_List = vector<Word_Entry>;


int main()
{
}
```

- http://ideone.com/9mCaq0 (C++) error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘Word_List’
- http://ideone.com/FdIKcr (C++11) success

You have a configuration error, you are not compiling with C++11 specification.

Comment: I believe g++ only supports this since version 4.7. [test with 4.7.2](http://liveworkspace.org/code/sgxSh$0), [test with 4.6.3](http://liveworkspace.org/code/sgxSh$1)